# In C#, how I can convert a comma separated key string to an actual value string?

Tags: c#, string, data-conversion

there is a database table called user, assume it has the following structure and value:

```
UserKey    UserName
------------------------
1          John Smith
2          Andrew Wright
3          David Morgan
4          Judy Brown
5          ........
```

In C#, can someone tell me how I can write a function/method to convert a key string separated by comma to a username string, also separated by comma. The UserKey and UserName matching are defined in the database table user. For example the function/method should convert string "`1,2,3,4"` to string `"John Smith,Andrew Wright,David Morgan,Judy Brown"`.

thank you very much!

Comment: Can you *cache* the RDBMS table into C# collection, say, `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: I am not sure, are you asking if I have the permission or want to do this way? I am not sure but certainly I want to try.

Answer (score 2):

You can try *caching* the Rdbms table into *C# collection*, say, `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
  Dictionary<string, string> cache = new Dictionary<string, string>();

  //TODO: I've assumed that RDBMS is MS SQL Server; put the right types here
  using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStringHere)) {
    conn.Open();

    string sql =
      @"select [UserKey],
               [UserName]
          from [User]";

    using (var q = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)) {
      using (var reader = q.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (reader.Read()) {
          cache.Add(Convert.ToString(reader[0]), Convert.ToString(reader[1]));
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Then you can query `cache` either with a help of *Linq*:

```
  string source = "1,2,3,4";

  string result = string.Join(",", source
    .Split(',')
    .Select(key => cache.TryGetValue(key.Trim(), out var name) ? name : "???"));
```

Or via regular expressions:

```
  string source = "1,2,3,4";

  string result = Regex.Replace(source, "[0-9]+", match =>
    cache.TryGetValue(match.Value, out var name) ? name : "???");
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dmitry for the help. I will try it tomorrow and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it. I have assumed that you have a way to look up user by id from your database (`GetUserFromDb`) already figured out, so I have just mimicked that part using a static array.

```
void Main()
{
    var userKeysString = "1,2,,xx,732,3,4";
    var userNamesString = GetUserNames(userKeysString); 
}

public string GetUserNames(string userKeys)
{
    var keys = userKeys.Split(",").Select(x => int.TryParse(x, out var i) ? i : 0);
    return string.Join(", ", keys.Where(k => k > 0).Select(k => GetUserFromDb(k)?.UserName).Where(u => u != null));
}

private User GetUserFromDb(int userKey)
{
    return AllDbUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserKey == userKey);
}

public static User[] AllDbUsers = new User[]
{
    new User { UserKey = 1, UserName = "John Smith"},
    new User { UserKey = 2, UserName = "Andrew Wright"},
    new User { UserKey = 3, UserName = "David Morgan"},
    new User { UserKey = 4, UserName = "Judy Brown"},
    new User { UserKey = 5, UserName = "John Doe"},
};

public class User
{
    public int UserKey { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Hiral for the help. I will try it tomorrow and let you know.